# Injecting MobX State Tree store into react components throwing error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

Issue: I am getting an error when attempting to inject a MST store into react class component:

`Error: Uncaught [Error: MobX injector: Store 'auth' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider`

the error stems from the LoginForm component posted below, and is nested under another component (not sure if this is the issue, as to say each component needs a `<Provider>`?)

component hierarchy:

```
Application (contains no Provider)
    |__ Authentication (contains no Provider)
        |__LoginForm
```

a little code:

```
import { AuthenticationStore } from './stores/AuthenticationStore'

const auth = AuthenticationStore.create()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider auth={auth}>
    <Application />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


//Application
const Application = inject('auth')(observer(class Application extends 
Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.auth) // logs the store as expected
    return (
      <div className={styles.applicationContainer}>
        <Authentication/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}))

export default Application

// LoginForm
const LoginForm = inject('auth')(observer(class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div></div>
    )
  }
}))

export default LoginForm
```

and to the question:

If not this, **what is the preferred protocol for passing the store to child components (without passing as props)?**

As always, thanks in advance for any and all input.  If this is a duplicate (I couldn't find this particular error), please mark as such and I will update accordingly...

Comment: The code in your question looks sound to me. Do you think you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: lemi try and spin one up

Comment: Well, this is obviously something else on my end, tests I assume:
https://codesandbox.io/s/9l5z2ox37y

Comment: YES!  *Confirmation, it is in my tests not liking the Provider...*